# CW approximation of a topological group

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, cw-complexes

Suppose we have a topologiacal group $G$. How do we construct a CW-complex $\bar{G}$ which is also a topological group, such that $\bar{G}\to G$ is a weak equivalence?

Comment: If $G$ has the (strong) homotopy type of a CW-complex, then any such CW-complex will easily be shown to be an $H$-group with the induced maps. I don't know whether we can find one that is an actual group, let alone for an arbitrary group